# Браузер не может найти картинку, переданную в тег

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, html5, django

передаю картинку из БД в шаблон, но браузер её почему-то не находит. Объясните пожалуйста почему и как это решить.

cat_of_plants.html:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="cotainer-content">
        {% for pl in plant %}
          <div class="latin_name">{{ pl.latin_name }}</div>
          <div class="image">
            <img src="{{ pl.image }}" alt="картинка не работает">
          </div>
          <div class="price">{{ pl.price }}</div>
          <div class="name">{{ pl.name }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import PlantsForm
from .models import plants
# Create your views here.
def cat_of_plants(request):
    Plants = plants.objects.all()
    return render(request,'content/cat_of_plants.html',context = {'plant': Plants})
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class plants(models.Model):
    latin_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', db_index = True)
    price = models.IntegerField(db_index = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: если браузер не видит, то картинки нету или неверный путь к картинке =)

Answer (score 2):

Вы забыли прописать свойство `url`. [Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url)

```
<img src="{{ pl.image.url }}" alt="картинка не работает">
```

Чтобы dev-сервер раздавал ваши медиа:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    # Ваши паттерны
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Еще раз прочтите документацию, иначе никак.

Comment: браузер мне пишет в консоли: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) и не выдает картинку

Comment: Так может этой картинки нет. Какой путь показывает браузер? Какой путь записан в бд? Какой путь стоит в настройках media?

Comment: Вдогонку вопрос: По какому пути сохранилась картинка в админке? (Путь отображается в поле после сохранения.)

Comment: @Jazzis, это у вас надо спросить, ибо в ыне предоставили конфигов проекта. Смотрите MEDIA_ROOT в настройках

Comment: @ZaArs Какой проект вас интересует?

Comment: логично, что ваш на django

Comment: @zakiroof У меня нет media_root в settings.py. Может есть какое-то значение по умолчанию?

Comment: сразу после добавления нового изображения в базу django создает в корне папку images в которую складирует изображения

Comment: @Desertdeveloper Какой путь показывает браузер?

Comment: @zakiroof, такой путь: http://127.0.0.1:8000/content/cat_of_plants/images/black-hole-1.jpg

Comment: @Desertdeveloper дополнил ответ